# Is it possible to configure the local mercurial repository to always push the current branch?

Tags: mercurial

The push command accepts a `-b` flag indicating which branch is to be pushed. But the default, without this flag is to push all the branches.

I want to know whether it is possible to change that default. Meaning pushing without the `-b` flag only pushes the current branch.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fake a command that does something like it:

```
[alias]
nudge = push --rev .
```

Which comes from [Steve Losh](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-09-28-nudge-a-gentler-push/).  That pushes the current revision, which is by definition on the current branch and all of its ancestors.

If you wanted to play with fire you could do:

```
[alias]
push = push --rev .
```

which would work until it doesn't -- which is to say when any other script or command tries to invoke push and expects it to push everything.

Better to go with nudge.

Comment: You've probably meant to say "and all of its **ancestors**".

Comment: But if current changeset *is not* (incidentally) HEAD of branch, you got "not a best result". -b "branch(.)"???

Comment: I think nudge as steve has it does what most folks expect most of the time. I stand by it.

Comment: I see from the comments in Steve Losh's post that there is also an option for specifying default push behavior for those using TortoiseHg: http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-09-28-nudge-a-gentler-push/#comment-752377542